# Polymorphic construction of a std::variant

Tags: c++, polymorphism, variant

I want to implement a simple error return type, i.e. a variant where one case indicates an error and the other indicates the succesfully computed result. For that task, I want to create error constructors like so:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename A> using result_t = std::variant<int, A> ;

template <typename T> result_t<T> make_left_int()
{
    return 42;
}

int main ()
{
    result_t<double> a = make_left_int();
    result_t<void*> b = make_left_int();

    std::cout << std::get<int>(a) << std::endl << std::get<int>(b) << std::endl;
}
```

The constrcutor `make_left_int` is polymorphic regardin the type of the success variant. But apparently, the C++ compiler cannot type it. It fails to infer the (unused) template argument T. Or rather it fails to unify it with `double` and `void*`.

Is there a way to have a function like that?

Comment: what about `auto a = make_left_int<double>()`?

Comment: `make_left_int` is not a constructor, and i dont understand in what way this function is polymorphic

Comment: What's wrong with the C++ native exception mechanism to report errors?

Comment: @Walter dangerous ground. You risk starting a religious war. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The constructor `make_left_int` ...

But `make_left_int` is not a constructor in C++. Unlike the functional language(s) whose terminology you're presumably using, a C++ constructor is a special method of a class, used to initialize instances of that class. It cannot be a free function which just *returns* an instance of that class.

> ... polymorphic regarding the type of the success variant

Yes, *but*: C++ template type deduction only operates on *arguments* to a function. For example,

```
template <typename T> T return_default() { return T{}; }
```

won't work in this code, because the return type is not available for deducing the type parameter T:

```
int i = return_default();
double d = return_default();
```

although you can still pass the type parameter explicitly:

```
int i = return_default<int>();
```

The simplest solution is the one _nh proposed in a comment: deduce the return type from the call, rather than the other way around (this avoids multiplying the places you need to specify the result type)

```
auto a = make_left_int<double>();
```

I suspect it would also be better style to specify what the member means, rather than where it sits in the record, like

```
auto a = error_result<double>(42);
```

or you could use an actual constructor, for your own variant-style class, ideally with a tag type to distinguish error codes from successes, in case the successful result could also be an int:

```
result<double> a(Error{42});
```

---

NB. *polymorphic* in C++ is often assumed to mean *runtime* polymorphism by default, as opposed to the static/compile-time polymorphism discussed here. If you're using the `template` keyword, you can always just say *template* and be understood.

Answer (score 0):

You can just let your `make_left_int()` return `int`, since any `result_t<T>` is constructible from an `int`. Note, however, that you might get into trouble with `result_t<int>`.

I recommend writing a `result` type yourself, not relying on `variant`. This has the benefit, that you can handle such cases (having a `result<int>`) and it allows you to handle access to the value when actually an error is stored, in your own way.

Comment: I don't like your recommendation to write code when the standard provides (almost) a solution already.

Comment: @Walter Totally agree on that in general. However, I think a solution crafted for this particular problem is much smoother to use. When working with 3d vectors, I'd rather implement a `Vector3` class, which I can nicely access and provide useful methods, instead of using a `std::tuple<float, float, float>` and large amounts of `std::get<0>()`, wouldn't you?